# Triggering delegated custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot seem to trigger this event at all. The story is, that I have some page that adds content dynamically, and I want to add events to these element's when they are made. (After `setup()`). But I cannot seem to trigger this custom event. I use this custom event to generate a jquery-ui slider. Here is my code:

```
function setup() {
    var determinant = $("#cat").text();
    $.post('../phpdatabase/setup.php', {
        categorija: determinant
    }, function(data) {
        $('#content').empty();
        $('#content').append(data);
    });
};



$(document).ready(function() {
    setup();
    $('body').on('click', '.colorbox', function() { //this works fine, .colorbox divs can be toggled on with clicks, they were dynamically added with setup()
        $(this).children().toggle();
    });
    $('body').on('myCustomEvent', '#slider-range', function() {
        alert("hye!"); //here I am to add some logic, but I just want an alert to work first. I can't seem to fire this event handler
    });
    $('body').trigger('myCustomEvent'); // I tried this, no luck.

});
```

I even tried this in jsfiddle:

```
var setup(){
    $('body').append('<div id="slider-range"></div>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   setup();
   $('body').on('myCustomEvent', '#slider-range', function() {
  alert("hye!");
        });
   $('#slider-range').trigger('myCustomEvent');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you've delegated your custom event. You either need to trigger the event on the `#slider-range` element so that it can bubble up to the `body` and be caught there:

```
$('#slider-range').trigger('myCustomEvent');
```

Or use a normal event handler and trigger the event directly on the `body` as you currently are.

```
$('body').on('myCustomEvent', function() {
    alert("hye!");
});
```

Comment: Odd, they both work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/em0g13on/ & https://jsfiddle.net/em0g13on/1/

Comment: I must have `$('body').on('myCustomEvent', '#slider-range0', function() {
        alert("hye!");
    });`

Comment: In which case use my first code example. You can see in the first fiddle link above it works fine.

Comment: But this does work with element, that are initially on the page. I tried it. But this #slider-range0 is added dynamically.

Comment: I tried this with a static element, worked fine, like this. Not with dynamic ones, I do not know how.

Comment: It still works when you append the element dynamically too: https://jsfiddle.net/em0g13on/2/

Comment: Check out my update. I tried that in fiddle and nothing. It seems when you add a function, it can't quite work like that.

Comment: The code in your fiddle doesn't work because `var setup() {...` isn't valid code. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/em0g13on/3/

Comment: I don't know what to do, I have this setup and it still doesn't work. ( I mean with my code.)

Answer (score 0):

Add callback to you code so that when the dynamically created HTML is bind to page, then events can be attached to them

Please see below code for your reference

```
    function setup(callback) {
        var determinant = $("#cat").text();
        $.post('../phpdatabase/setup.php', {
            categorija: determinant
        }, function(data) {
            $('#content').empty();
            $('#content').append(data);
        });
        callback(true);
    };


$(document).ready(function() {
    setup(function(data){
        //call event code
    });
});
```